# Create MySql schema in the model in express application

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express-MVC-generator for creating app skeleton in node js and once I have my project structured, I need to change default database in mongo for a MySQL database but I can´t find how to create a MySQL schema from database in the model file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research over the web, I found that the best option to solve my problem is to use sequelize, sequelize-cli to generate the models from an existing database. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cli